# How to check that windows application running second time

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I check that the application is running more than one time in a day. like postback in asp.net webform.

I want to run a query on every 1st date of every month. My Application will check system date time if date is 1 then run the query but problem is that when application runs second time then again it runs a query.

I want to run query only one time on that day.

Comment: are you familiar with Mutexes..? convert the application to either as `Windows Service || Console.Application` then attach a Scheduler to have it launch only once a day..

Comment: @MethodMan Mutex has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: You will most likely need some sort of external data source, such as a file or a database to store whether is has run. When it runs, you store it, then when you launch the application again, it checks to see if it has already run on that day.

Comment: Perhaps use a config file? When your application is done running the query, write the current date. When your application starts, check if the day is 1 AND that the date in the config is not the same day, to prevent it from running twice.

Comment: It has everything to do with his question.. not to mention it's a viable solution otherwise if he wants to get all fancy and start using the windows registry and things of that nature to control the singleton he's free to do that too

Comment: @MethodMan I think the question is not about concurrency. It's about running the application twice on the same day, not at the same time.

Comment: @MethodMan Care to explain what do you mean by "It has everything to do with his question." At the moment you seem to be very abstract. I guess you misunderstand the question.

Comment: the question needs to be revised then.. because I can see it from meaning at least 2 different things.. if he wants a quick and dirty then I would use something as simple as a 2 database field  date, and hasrun, to check the running and setting a flag once it has been run..

Comment: @SriramSakthivel if I read how to check if the application is running a second time.. then if it's running and one tried to launch it again yet it' already running.. then a Mutex would be why I suggested that as a viable check.. this question has double meaning in my opinion

Comment: @MethodMan If you have read the question fully, you wouldn't have got this confusion. It is pretty clear from these statements what OP wants "My Application will check system date time if date is 1 then run the query but problem is that when application runs second time then again it runs a query. i want to run query only one time on that day"

Comment: @MethodMan The question is pretty clear: The guy wants to check only once a day if a certain program is running. If you launch the application a second time on the same day, he does not want to check yet again if the certain program is running.

Comment: Still I think that the config file or a text file or a database idea is good. thanks to all for cooperation. Thanks all of you.

Comment: What jwatts1980 said, although I'd definitely use a local file since database would be an overkill for this. Use the file to store the date each time your application is launched and on each launch check if it has already been launched on that date.

Comment: I got this but again this also has a problem that if the system date is changed then what to do? how can i get global date from server without getting date from the system?

Comment: I'd **ask** the server on every launch and store on server side if the query has been executed or not (and then run it). All using server date (if not a local db) to prevent the user from changing it.

Answer (score 0):

Excuse for my bad English.

You can create a variable in project properties->setting. increment your variable for each run of application.

[Using Setting in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869(v=vs.80).aspx)